# Postman not working with PostgreSQL, but Postgres CLI works fine

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend

so I just recently started learning Postgres, and am currently following a course on youtube for the PERN stack, link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldYcgPKEZC8&list=PLxoaUpJNrj0ROloAVu1QedaYfH4Nboe2G&index=4

Now, I git cloned this guy's repository, created my user, changed the db.js file, started the server, and when I try to insert some data, or do a get request with postman, it just says sending request... forever.

I have installed Postgres on my laptop, and when I try to insert data into a table from the terminal or display the inserted data by typing the SELECT * FROM todo; command, it works fine, but postman doesn't work at all.

Does anyone have any idea as to why it is not working? I'm on Linux Mint if that might be relatable.

Comment: Not sure what "my laptops password" means - but you need to provide the password of the **database** user, not "of your laptop" (which is the operating system)

Comment: But I am using the default user, and I do not have a password configured for that user, but if I just make it empty or remove that field it still does not work.